# Should I group related parameters in a struct at public Interface?

Tags: c++, api, dll

I plan to export a API that can save the report into a JPEG image like this

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IImageSaving, IUnknown) 
{
    ...
    HRESULT SaveReport(
        const wchar_t* imageFilepath,
        unsigned int imageFormat,
        float imageQuality,
        bool imageAlphaSupport,

        unsigned int reportDetailLevel,
        long long reportTime,
        const wchar_t* reportAuthor,
    );
    ...
}
```

I am concerned that there are too many parameters in this API. Should I export two structs and put those relate parameters in struct? like this

```
struct ImageDesc
{        
    const wchar_t* imageFilepath;
    unsigned int imageFormat;
    float imageQuality;
    bool imageAlphaSupport;
};

struct ReportDesc
{        
    unsigned int reportDetailLevel;
    long long reportTime;
    const wchar_t* reportAuthor;
};

DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IImageSaving, IUnknown) 
{
    ...
    HRESULT SaveReport(
        const ImageDesc& imageDesc,
        const ReportDesc& reportDesc
    );
    ...
}
```

I prefer group related parameters into one struct when too many parameters needed in function. It is more clear to tell what these parameters are. But I don't know whether there could be a problem(maintenance, usability, or etc..) in boundary area.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is always good to group related parameters into one struct. And I suppose, there will be no maintenance problem raise with this kind of coding..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mandatory information here is the file name, so first thing I would do is to pass it as a separate parameter.

I would rather have default values for all other parameters and specific functions to change them.

If you're going for your two structures, you will either force the user to specify values he/she might have no clue about or no interest in specifying, or have to provide a function to initialize these structures to default values (à la POSIX, which was a fine circa 1990 C interface, but it's 2015 now).

You could also have a convention saying you can pass NULL ptrs to get default values, but that tends to produce ugly code sprinkled with calls like `do_something (whatever, NULL, NULL);`

At any rate, grouping parameters is already a big improvement over passing them individually. We don't need another Microsoft API :).

Comment: Maybe I can hint the default value of parameters in struct's constructor parameters?

Comment: You could, but that would still force all users to initialize a struct holding data they might not care about. Typically, most users won't care about the `ReportData` structure, so better design an interface where these informations can be ignored completely.